# Json php decoding issue

Tags: php, json

In fact Im having some troubles with php script that i have made recently. The problem is that I can't get data from a json file `damo.json` using php. This is the code of the json file:

```
{ "checkouts":[
    {
    "billing_address":{
    "country":"Italy",
    "first_name":"christian"
    }
    },
    {
    "billing_address":{
    "country":"Italy",
    "first_name":"christian"
    }
    }
    ]
    }
```

i want to get the first_name record. Is it possible using php ?
this is the php code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('demo.json');
$obj = json_decode($data);
foreach ($obj->billing_address as $result)
{
    echo $result->name;
}

?>
```

Comment: That JSON is not valid JSON. So - probably, once you munge your custom data format into something recognisable.

Comment: @Quentin ive just made mistake while copying the code

Comment: You missed the first opening curl brace at the beginning.

Comment: @YassineDevlopper — Then the answer is still "yes" and you should read PHP's JSON documentation. http://php.net/json

Comment: why do not you put also the php script that you made?

Comment: @manix done ! check it please

Answer (score 0):

After you fix your syntax as noted above load the file and use json_decode with first parameter the json and second parameter true for associative array.

```
$data = file_get_contents( "demo.json" );
$data = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($data);//you have assoc array
```

Comment: Well, correct me if I am lost, but, the people does not answer this question because the user did not take the time to read and investigate a relative easy question that could be resolved with a research at this site.